# Função move_uploaded_file do PHP retorna false

Tags: php

A função move_uploaded_file retorna false, mesmo com o valor de $_FILES['arquivo']['error'] retornando 0.

A pasta onde os códigos se encontram já estão com a permissão 777.

```php
<?php
    if(isset($_FILES["arquivo"])){
        $upload_dir = '/arquivo';
        $arquivo_name = $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["arquivo"]["tmp_name"], "$upload_dir/$arquivo_name")){
            echo "Arquivo movido com sucesso!";
        }else{
            echo "Não foi dessa vez";
        }

    }
?>
```

Usando a função print_r($_FILES["arquivo"]) eu obtenho o seguinte retorno

```
Array ( [name] => JPG-Alta-Qualidade.jpg [full_path] => JPG-Alta-Qualidade.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpA6fDmM [error] => 0 [size] => 153690 )
```

Comment: vide instruções já dadas da 1a vez que perguntou https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/569575/fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-move-uploaded-file-do-php-retornando-false#comment1003055_569575 - com base nisso pode restaurar a pergunta original e editar. Ao editar, a postagem vai para uma reavaliação.